# Netflix refusing to log in, tried all the typical solutions

Tags: nexus-7, 4.3-jelly-bean, netflix

Just got my new tablet, tried to get netflix running. I took the following steps.

1. Installed netflix, got 15001 error
2. Ran system update, I am now completely up-to-date, error no longer occurs
3. attempted to sign in, got the following error message:

   "we're unable to connect you to netflix please try again later"
4. cleared cache, deleted local data, got the same error message
5. uninstalled app, reinstalled, got the same error message
6. uninstalled app, restart tablet, installed app. Got the same error message

I only get this error message when using the correct username/password, using a bad one gives an appropriate error. So it's not a connection issue, just an authentication one. I have no idea what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

Netflix has a [troubleshooting guide for Android devices](https://support.netflix.com/en/node/461).

See if any of them works. If not, share your findings.

Comment: I have already tried all of the steps listed there. Like I said in my question: This is not a connectivity issue, it is an authentication issue. The error message doesn't even show up in netflix's help center search.

Comment: @AdamSpurgin Can you log-in via the website though? Log-out first, then log-in.